# How can I emit error event in jest and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

For example, I'm using [Archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver):

```
archive.on('error', err => {
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback.call(this, err);
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

These lines are uncovered according to jest.  How can you emit this error?  A mock?

Comment: Are you using `es6` imports or `require`?

Comment: I'm using es6:
`import archiver from 'archiver';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your callbacks to other module and then export it, like:

```
//calbacks.js

const errorCallback = callback => err => {
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback.call(this, err);
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
}

export {errorCallback} // es6 named export
```

Then you can import it in your main file:

```
import { errorCallback } from "./callbacks.js" //path should be correct, this would work if you have both files in same directory

...

archive.on('error', errorCallback(callback)) //pass callback to curried function
```

You can also just import it in `spec` and test it:

```
const spy = jest.fn()

errorCallback(fn)("error")    
expect(spy).toBeCalledWith("error");
```

and also test case when callback is not function:

```
expect(() => {
    errorCallback("notFunction")("error")
}).toThrow()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'm trying this out now, but I'm a little fuzzy on how the callback.js would look in typescript - `callback`, `err`, and `this` are no longer inferred

Comment: Changed callback to:
```const errorCallback = (callback: any) => (err: any) => {
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(err);
  } ...```

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. Your error is just javascript error? Maybe `Error => void` would work for `callback` and `Error` for `err`?